# Rails 4 - Dynamic content with modal and tabs issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

---

Edit for more clarification: Once I hit the submit, the controller action happens, but the modal just doesn't disappear and refresh the page. This was working before I added the tabs, but now it does not.

---

I have a rails app that I use to update associations between various tables. So far I have been able to open the a modal with a form that has a checklist for user to update the links between records.

```
<div class= "form-group" style="overflow-y auto; height: 200px;">
  <p><strong>Associated Things </strong></p>
  <% for thing in Thing.All %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag "bigthings[thing_ids][]", thing.id, @bigthings.things.include?(thing) %>
      <%= thing.name %>
    </div>
  <%end%>
</div>
<div class= "modal-footer">
   <%= button_tag(type:"submit", class:"btn btn-default") do %> Submit<%end%>
   <% link_to "Cancel", class: "btn btn-default", data: {dismiss: "modal"}%>
</div>
```

Now, this form code (not complete, but correct) was originally closing after I hit the submit button because in the update_links.js.erb that this form routes to says

```
  $("#update-modal").on("submit", function(){
      $("#update-modal").modal("hide");
     window.location.reload();
});
```

On the bigthing#show, I had a table that dynamically update once submit was hit on the modal

```
<table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @bigthing.things.each do |thing| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= @thing.name %></td>
            <td><%= thing.price %></td>
          <tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now, I added tabs to this section to show things based on the owner of the big things. One tab shows all the things associated with the big thing but the second tab shows all the things associated with the owner of the big things.

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" 
            data-toggle="tab">Mine</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
        </ul>
 <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
<table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <% @bigthing.owner.things.each do |thing| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= @thing.name %></td>
                <td><%= thing.price %></td>
              <tr>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
<table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <% @bigthing.things.each do |thing| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= @thing.name %></td>
                <td><%= thing.price %></td>
              <tr>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
     $(function(){
       $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

</script>
```

But now when I open the form to update the things, the modal doesn't close on submit. But if I close out of the modal and refresh the page, the updated associations appear. Anyone see something I'm missing.

Comment: `<% for thing in Thing.All %>` does seem rather unusual. I'd expect to see `<% Thing.all.each do |thing| %>` Is there actually an `All` method? In Ruby names are almost always all lowercase with underscores if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Install this gem

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

jQuery plugin for drop-in fix binded events problem caused by Turbolinks

This could be you issue.

Comment: NO, these is another gem to fix an issue with turbolink and jquery; check again the gem name

Comment: I added that gem with no success. Modal box is still not hiding even though the backend database manipulation is working.